# Add consistent value to cells corresponding with loop and paste special

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have code that posts data from sheet 2 into the first blank cells available in sheet 1 (under the A, B, and C columns). This code works great.
But, where I place these cells I need a value of 1000 to go in column D and end when A, B, and C end. Also, for formatting issues, I need it to come in as being PasteSpecial xlPasteValue.
I've pasted my code below. I appreciate any help.

```
Sub NextTryThis()
'====Code here works===
LastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
BlankRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
BlankRowB = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
BlankRowC = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
BlankRowD = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 2 To LastRow2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & BlankRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    BlankRow = BlankRow + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To LastRow2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & BlankRowB).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    BlankRowB = BlankRowB + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To LastRow2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & BlankRowC).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    BlankRowC = BlankRowC + 1
Next i

'========Here is my problem=====
Dim DivideBy As Integer
DivideBy = 1000

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D" & BlankRowD).Value = DivideBy

For i = BlankRowD To x '===x is denoting wherever A, B, and C stop==='
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & BlankRowD).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValue
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in D?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.  Setting the range to copy over is very useful, because then you can resize to the range's row and/or column count, which makes putting in the 1000's in column D easy:

```
Sub NextTryThis()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set rngCopy = ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 2))
    If rngCopy.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data

    With ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        'Get just the values from rngCopy to the next blank row in ws1
        .Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value

        'Put the desired number in column D for the copied data rows
        .Offset(, 3).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = 1000
    End With

End Sub
```